# support parameter info tooltip for a new language in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, parameters, tooltip

I am trying to support intellisense for a new language using Visual Studio SDK. Right now I am working on Parameter Info Tooltip. The problem I am facing is that the tooltip is shown when I type open parenthesis but it disappears when I start typing a parameter. I have used StartParameters, NextParameter and EndParameters methods as mentioned in msdn which internally calls GetMethods function to obtain the parameter values. Here I need to enable the triggers ParameterStart, ParameterNext and ParameterEnd before calling these functions. What should I do to keep showing the tooltip when I am typing the parameters?